# Primefaces datatable colspan column width - Not Working

Tags: html, css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i try to create a primefaces datatable with fixed column width for some(not all) columns.
The tableheader got 3 rows with colspan and rowspan. I want now to fix the width of the first column under "a". The second column should be dynamic.

Without Colspan i could use the width attribute of the Header Column element. But now i cant use the header column because it is for two columns. The width for the normal Column is ignored. (width="30" and style="width:30px;")

I added a screenshot of my Problem(http://s14.directupload.net/images/140717/z2a7vbrj.png). The first Table is correct and complete HTML(self written) the second Table is primefaces datatable seen in the following code snippet:

```
<p:dataTable var="produktkenntniss"
            value="#{xyz}">

            <p:columnGroup type="header">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column rowspan="3" colspan="2"
                        headerText="a" />
                    <p:column colspan="2"
                        headerText="b" />
                    <p:column colspan="5"
                        headerText="c" />
                    <p:column rowspan="3"
                        headerText="d" />
                </p:row>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column rowspan="2"
                        headerText="e" />
                    <p:column rowspan="2"
                        headerText="f" />
                    <p:column colspan="2"
                        headerText="g" />
                    <p:column colspan="2"
                        headerText="h" />
                    <p:column headerText="i" />
                </p:row>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column
                        headerText="j" />
                    <p:column headerText="k" />
                    <p:column
                        headerText="l" />
                    <p:column headerText="m" />
                </p:row>
            </p:columnGroup>

            <p:column width="30">
                <h:outputText
                    value="n" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText
                    value="o" />
            </p:column>
            ...
```

I hope someone can help me!

Best regards

Simon

Answer (score 0):

I am using PrimeFaces 5 and I'm having the same issue. I did not find the Primefaces way to solve this issue but you can use simple CSS styling in primefaces tags and it will work:

```
        <p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column rowspan="2" style="width:10%" headerText="a"></p:column>
            <p:column rowspan="2" style="width:5%" headerText="c"></p:column>
            <p:column rowspan="2" style="width:5%" headerText="c"></p:column>
```

The style attribute is recognized in the p:column tags **within the columnGroup**, and is rendered without modification by PrimeFaces.

In your case you have applied the style to the p:column tags which are not in the columnGroup.

All best,

Loic

Answer (score 0):

it is unsupported with scrollable datatable, have a look at ([Datatable Scrollable with Grouping column width issue](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=32106))