# Primefaces Group Table Set Column Width Manually

Tags: html, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 5 and with a Group data table with more than 150 columns. I am trying to set each column width manually. I tried the threads here, but still primefaces is auto adjusting my column widths to show all columns in one screen without any horizontal scrolling. I am looking for one place to set the column width in px or %. 
I am not sure how to approach with Group Heading.

I tried so far:

```
resizableColumns="true" style="table-layout: fixed"
Set style="width:auto" and
```

set in css:

```
.repoTab.ui-datatable table { width: auto !important; }
```

My xhtml here:

```
<h:form>
<p:dataTable id="userTable" value="#{userDAO.data}" var="ub"
    binding="#{userBean.dataTable}" paginator="true" rows="500"
    resizableColumns="true" style="table-layout: fixed">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:toolbar>
            <!-- Header Codes Here -->
        </p:toolbar>
    </f:facet>
    <p:columnGroup type="header">

        <p:row>
            <p:column colspan="3" headerText="Application" style="width:auto" />
            <!-- <p:column colspan="6" headerText="Primary" width="100%" /> -->
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
            <!-- ************ Application ************* -->
            <p:column colspan="3" headerText="Key" style="width:auto" />
            <!-- ************ Primary ************* -->
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
            <!-- ************ Appl Key ************* -->
            <p:column headerText="Id" width="50" />
            <p:column headerText="F Name" width="150" />
            <p:column headerText="L Name" width="150" />

        </p:row>
    </p:columnGroup>

    <p:column headerText="Id" width="50">
        <h:outputText value="#{userBean.dataTable.rowIndex+1}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="First Name">
        <h:outputText value="#{ub.firstName}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Last Name">
        <h:outputText value="#{ub.lastName}" />
    </p:column> -->         
  </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
</html>
```

Comment: I found that If I add any column group, then I am loosing all fixed width settings that I provide for each column. I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I saw the same question here as unresolved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807411/primefaces-datatable-colspan-column-width-not-working

Comment: .ui-datatable table{
    width:auto!important;
}
Should work.

Comment: @vels4J, It didn't work, I already did that and mentioned in question under _set in css:_

Answer (score 2):

Keep your table CSS style:

```
.ui-datatable table { width: auto !important; }
```

Remove the **width** attribute and set the **min-width** on the columns style:

```
<p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>
        <!-- ... -->
    </p:row>
    <p:row>
        <p:column headerText="Id" style="min-width: 50px;" />
        <p:column headerText="F Name" style="min-width: 150px;" />
        <p:column headerText="L Name" style="min-width: 150px;" />
    </p:row>
</p:columnGroup>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: also , you can use `width` value

Answer (score -4):

I solved it by adding `expandableRowGroups="true"`, then I could use the style property.

```
<p:dataTable expandableRowGroups="true" scrollable="true" >
<p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>
        <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="txt" style="width:50px;" />
    </p:row>
</p:columnGroup>
</p:dataTable>
```